# Should I sell the seal of hallownest?

Tags: hollow-knight

I found a NPC that buys rare items in the **City of Tears**. Should I sell these items, or will I need them for something?

The only item that he will buy right now is the **seal of hallownest**. Is this item useful for any other purpose?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The only thing you can do with [Hallownest Seal](http://hollowknight.wikia.com/wiki/Hallownest_Seal), [Wanderer's Journal](http://hollowknight.wikia.com/wiki/Wanderer%27s_Journal), [King's Idol](http://hollowknight.wikia.com/wiki/King%27s_Idol), and [Arcane Egg](http://hollowknight.wikia.com/wiki/Arcane_Egg) is sell them to Relic Seeker Lemm for Geo.

If you don't need the Geo right away, consider waiting to sell them because unlike your Geo, these items are retained on death. You can think of them as a safer way to keep large amounts of Geo.